# Using https with Identity Server 4

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have followed all the IS4 tutorials here although none highlight how to use the https protocol in prod.  I might have missed something but when I deploy my IS4 server in IIS using https (using a cert I have installed on the IIS server) I can no longer call `tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync`. It simply returns **Error=Unauthorised** and **ErrorType=Http** as shown in the image:
[image]

My IS4 is setup as such

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
//.AddSigningCredential(cert)
.AddTemporarySigningCredential()...;
```

I have also tried using the same SSL cert but with no progress.

EDIT (Answer):
Arghhh! I had basic authentication enabled on my deployed IIS site which was causing that error, after disabling it, it worked as expected

Comment: Are you able to brose to the https://<iishostname>/.well-known/openid-configuration.if any errors for that

Comment: @RohithRajan yes, I can browse to that, no problem with that

Comment: Do you have any luck on that?

Comment: It was just a problem of having basic authentication enabled, I added an edit to my answer a while back. Thanks for your suggestion though

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there are two ways to add https. On your startup project you can add the following code in `ConfigureServices` method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services.AddMvc();

    if (!_env.IsDevelopment())
        services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions>(o =>
            o.Filters.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute()));
    //...
}
```

Or adding the `RequireHttps` attribute into your controller, plus Enabling SSL