How to user authenticate using http in identity server?
Using usehttpsredirection user is authenticated properly. But when I comment out the usehttpsredirection and change security policy from CookieSecurePolicy.Always to CookieSecurePolicy.None, I am facing am issue with when am login user details user not authenticated.
Can you please help me?
Using Usehttpsredirection is working fine.
But I want to use it with http only. In that case am commenting out Usehttpsredirection and the user is not authenticated.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896207/using-https-with-identity-server-4#:~:text=I%20might%20have%20missed%20something%20but%20when%20I%20deploy%20my

You must use HTTPS between the browser and the Client and IdentityServer. You can use HTTP between the client/API and IdentityServer.
Why?
Because some of the important cookies set during authentication will be blocked by the browser (due to the samesite rules).
I did blog about how to Debugging cookie problems in ASP.NET Core.
